# I/O errors when reading & writing downloads and uploads to NTFS drives

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, ntfs

I've had a good look around but can't find a fix - the only thing I think it could be from what I've seen is that I don't have full permission for my drives, but I've changed the settings in the files interface.

My Windows desktop started having boot errors so I installed Ubuntu onto my C drive. I have a D and E internal drives as well, which are still NTFS. They're used for file storage, no OS or applications on them.

I can access them from the files manager in Ubuntu, copy and paste files from them, but I am getting I&O errors when I try to download torrents to them via qbittorrent, and I am also getting access permission errors when I try to upload photos stored on them to a website via Chromium.

If anyone was able to help I'd really appreciate it! Thanks

Comment: How do you mount the NTFS drives ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to add or delete to internal hard disk (Not a file permission issue)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039246/unable-to-add-or-delete-to-internal-hard-disk-not-a-file-permission-issue)

Comment: That's not Ubuntu problem, that's just windows thing. Try disabling fast boot.

Comment: Did you erase Windows and install Ubuntu or is your system a dual boot of Windows and Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Windows has hybrid shutdown and then, Ubuntu can not wrtie to NTFS.

A real full shutdown of Windows allows the ntfs partitions to be mounted with R/W perms by Ubuntu.

For a full shutdown of windows, hold the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key as you press the "Shut down" button. You may also disable the 'fast startup' feature in the Windows power control panel.

[image]